# How to get the full path of a file properly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I've  to add a script to windows registry via command line as follow:

```
Reg add HKCU\Software\...\.\.. /v backUp /t REG_SZ  /d "%~dp0\backUp.bat" /f
```

The script is called "setup.bat" it contains only the above line. BTW backUp.bat is running at the same dir as the "setup.bat" so for that i'm using %~dp0 to get the full path of the script dir. I surrounded %~dp0 by ", because some path contains spaces.. So, normally when i run i set properly the full path of the backUp.bat, whenever the script is running, but the problem is that i get a double slash before backUp.bat in my registry, look:

```
C:\Users\marwen\Desktop\bin\\backUp.bat
```

If i change the command as this:

```
Reg add HKCU\Software\...\.\.. /v backUp /t REG_SZ  /d "%~dp0"\backUp.bat /f
```

Same here, the result is faulty :

```
C:\Users\marwen\Desktop\bin"\backUp.bat
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested but `Reg add HKCU\Software\...\.\.. /v backUp /t REG_SZ  /d "%~dp0backUp.bat" /f` without the slash should do it.

Comment: Works.., this really silly, notepad++ highlight it as a string.. anyway thank you!